# Django passing Matlpotlib image as variable

Tags: python, html, django, matplotlib, web-frontend

I am trying to display a Matplotlib graph image as a variable in the .html but am unsuccessful. I am new to Django, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I get the following image when I go to the HTML page:

[image: html page]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import sys
import platform
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta, date
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pylab import *
import io

inside views.py

def submit(request):

    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    y = [5, 2, 6, 8, 2, 7]
    plot(x, y, linewidth=2)
    xlabel('x-axis')
    ylabel('yaxis')
    title('sample graph')
    grid(True)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    plt.close()
    plt_bytes = buf.getvalue()
    buf.close()

    return render(request, 'jobs_app/index.html', {'path': plt_bytes})
```

Inside index.html:

```
< img src="{{ path }}">
```

The Error code received in the terminal console is 
[22/Jun/2018 18:39:04] "POST /Home/submit HTTP/1.1" 200 95021
Not Found: /Home/b'/x89PNG/r/n/x1a/n/x00/x00/x00/rIHDR/x00/x00/x02/x80/x00/x00/x01/xe0/x08/x06/x00/x00/x005/xd1/xdc/xe4/x00/x00/x00/x04sBIT/x08/x08/x08/x08|/x08d/x88/x00/x00/x00/tpHYs/x00/x00/x0fa/x00/x00/x0fa/x01/xa8